# Content type with custom forms in many site collections

Tags: 2013, office-365, custom-form, custom

I developed a custom form for a Content Type but it seems that I cannot have the files referenced outside my site collection so I included the file in the site Collection, Let's say know that I have to create three new site collections and use my CT with my custom forms. So everytime I do a change in the form I have to go to every site collection that has my CT and change the file.

Is there a better way to do this? I don't want to use a feature since I cannot use features in Office 365. What should I use or develop to achieve this?

Comment: Cant you use your content type hub (https://yourtenant.sharepoint.com/sites/contenttypehub) and syndicate it out to your site collections?

Comment: Yes, I did that, so now I can see my CT in the other site collections but I cannot see the files that are included in my content type hub. I'm getting an error that says that I'm trying to redirect and the page is not a singing page. That's why I decided to include the files in every site collection

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same issue before. Content type hub is not sync quickly it takes some time to take effect. So i am doing updates programmatically for all site collections.

Comment: there is a Job you have to run after you publish the Content Type in order to update the content type in all the site collections, it's called "Content Type Subscriber"... However my question wasn't about this